Save exact scroll position in SwiftUI
Does anyone know how to save exact scroll position to app storage in SwiftUI, so like if you kill the app or navigate to other views, the exact scroll position of the ScrollView is saved? Can you achieve this with a LazyVStack?
I tried using IDs from items but it didn't work.

you could try using UserDefaults or @AppStorage to save then bring back the scroll position value.

Use SceneStorage not AppStorage

I believe the OP is asking rather how to get the position in a scrollView, rather than how to perform the save operation.
In iOS 17, there is the .scrollPosition modifier that works with a scrollView. It monitors a target layout and is aware of the ids of items present in view. You can watch Apple's video on it.

AFAIK, with SceneStorage, the data is only available within the specific scene
and will be lost when the scene is closed. Whereas with AppStorage,
the data will persist even after the app is closed and reopened.
Re: the question, @27shutterclicks could be right,
but this is not what the words say: Save exact scroll position in SwiftUI.
